# Required tags on the main site

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

Meta site has a set of special tags: [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)
[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)
[support](/questions/tagged/support)
[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

At least one of them is required to ask a question on meta.

What about the main site? Is it possible to make tags with winning creteria required? Also I would've add [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) and [experimental-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experimental-challenge) to the list.